# Are PWA sites in same domain not able to install both on home screen?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I created 2 PWA sites
https://s.maplat.jp/r/naramap and https://s.maplat.jp/r/aizumap

But these are not able to install on home screen together.
Once the one installed, the other cannot install.

Are there any specifications or limitations to install PWAs on same domain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can accomplish this with scoped apps. Update your [manifest files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) to include a `scope` parameter with a value of the path that "app" should be served under.

```
"scope": "/r/aizumap/",
```

and

```
"scope": "/r/naramap/",
```

You can still be able to use a single service worker but each sub app will need to have a trailing `/` in it's path for the `start_url`/`scope` to work.

You can see a [sample](https://nebula-cross.glitch.me/) I've made and the [source](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nebula-cross). It has a parent app, and two sub apps.

Comment: Dividing two apps into different sub directories is also impossible for my use case...only I can do is providing different service workers for two apps.
Hence I want to know if providing different service workers will solve this issue or not.

Comment: In ios, what I observe is that due to scoping, even the localstorage space is not shared between two scoped apps, where as in chrome android, it is shared.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two apps in same domain, map it to two different sub-domain with one service works for each of the sub-domain.
That will enable you to host it as a two different PWA and both can be added to home screen.

```
https://s.maplat.jp/r/naramap -> https://naramap.maplat.jp/r/ 

https://s.maplat.jp/r/aizumap -> https://aizumap.maplat.jp/r/
```

Comment: I can't divide them in different sub domains..if I divide service workers, then they can be installed separately?

Comment: And if you know the specification written about this, would you please tell me the place of specification document?

Comment: Getting odd behavior in Samsung Internet (9.2.10.15). Can only add all three to *Apps Screen* if I add Kitchen last