# Multiple PWAs in the same domain

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to host multiple PWAs under same endpoint. Say, I have three different PWAs Under root and then root should host these 3 PWAs in such a way that when I switch to any other apps via link or menu it shouldn't open in different window. Currently, it is getting opened in different window as web app whenever, I am clicking on different app.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 11):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548573/are-pwa-sites-in-same-domain-not-able-to-install-both-on-home-screen). It stated that you can accomplish this with scoped apps.

> Update your [manifest
>   files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) to
>   include a `scope` parameter with a value of the path that "app" should
>   be served under.
>
> ```
> "scope": "/r/aizumap/",
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> "scope": "/r/naramap/",
> ```
>
> You can still be able to use a single service worker but each sub app
>   will need to have a trailing `/` in it's path for the
>   `start_url/scope` to work.

Here's a [sample](https://nebula-cross.glitch.me/) and a [source](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nebula-cross?path=README.md:1:0) which might also help.

Comment: I don't think this accomplishes what the question was asking, but I think it's the right answer. You can't have two PWA's that have the same scope.

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple PWA when you can

1) Split the app into multiple web app to have one Manifest.json and one service worker for each of them.

2) Host it under different URL

- Say https://example.com/myFirstApp/ and
- https://example.com/myOtherApp/ - 
  Place Manifest and SW under each of these path.

You can't have more than one PWA when you have only one Manifest and one SW registered for one path, as these two things essentially defines a unique PWA with a unique scope(URL under which the app is accessible)

Comment: When a PWA in iOS Safari is added to homescreen, iOS strips the directories from the URL, so when you open the PWA from the homescreen, it will just be https://example.com

Comment: @chaserino That is not the case. iOS will only strip the url down to the root folder of the app. 
I have an app located in domain.com/da and iOS does not strip the /da part. After reading your comment, I confirmed it by setting up a proxy between the iOS device and the internet. The first request made after opening the app from the homescreen was directed at domain.com/da.