# pwa prompt for multiple paths of same domain

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have set up multiple paths (with different manifests) to create a PWA per path e.g. `domain/path1` and `domain/path2`. This is as per the following SO link:

[Multiple PWAs in the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280821/multiple-pwas-in-the-same-domain)

Further, I am using the window `beforeinstallprompt` event to prompt the user to install the pwa. I notice that if the PWA is installed say for path1 then when the user invokes path2 it does not call this event and consequently I am not able to enable the `install` button. In fact, the `install app` from the menu (in Android or the desktop + sign) too does not appear.

I assume this is because the scope in the manifest is the same. What would be the work around for this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have different `start_url` values in each manifest?

Comment: Yes @JeffPosnick. What seems to work is to get the scope and start_url the same viz. scope = "/path1" and start_url = "/path1". I just tried it and seems to work and downloads both with different icons etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving this from the comments to the answer section so that it's more visible:

*What seems to work is to get the `scope` and `start_url` the same viz. `scope = "/path1"` and `start_url = "/path1"`. I just tried it and seems to work and downloads both with different icons etc.*