# Multiple PWAs from same Application - next-pwa

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json, next-pwa

Is it possible to define different paths/routes from the same application to have different PWAs from the same NextJS app using next-pwa?

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280821/multiple-pwas-in-the-same-domain) and it's useful but while i'm working on next-pwa i don't figure out how to do it.

Since it's only one withPWA hoc that wraps next config i guess it's not possible?

Any ideas?